# With what word might I substitute 'forward-thinking'?

Tags: word-choice

I wrote the following sentence:

> Driverless cars have already been tried by forward-thinking countries.

Yet, I am not sure if ***forward-thinking*** is the best choice. What other word could be chosen instead of ***forward-thinking***?

Comment: Not really a verb but a great phrase is "ahead of its time"

Comment: @Inazuma _forward-thinking_ is a participial **adjective** here.

Comment: Define *forward-thinking*.

Comment: 'innovative' might work.

Comment: countries that focus on the future: future-focused countries.

Answer (score 4):

Anyone of the following should do:

- [visionary](http://www.aamboli.com/translate/visionary)
- [anticipatory](http://www.aamboli.com/translate/anticipatory)
- [futuristic](http://www.aamboli.com/translate/futuristic)

Comment: I like "visionary."

Answer (score 2):

Consider using ***progressive***, defined by Merriam-Webster as [*making use of or interested in new ideas, findings, or opportunities*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/progressive) and [*moving forward or onward*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/progressive).

You seem to be using the term ‘forward-thinking’ with an *approving* sense of ‘not constrained by existing thinking’, and/or ‘*constructively* pushing ahead’. ***Progressive*** is commonly used for this purpose.

Depending on your *specific* intent in this composition, however, other potentially useful terms exist (all linked definitions here are from Merriam-Webster)...

***liberal*** (suggesting ‘actively interested in possible new ideas and approaches’): [*not opposed to new ideas or ways of behaving that are not traditional or widely accepted*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/liberal)

***broad-minded*** (suggesting ‘open to new and challenging ideas’): [*willing to accept opinions, beliefs, or behaviors that are unusual or different from your own*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/broadminded)

***radical*** (suggesting ‘happy to depart from conventional practice’):  [*favoring extreme changes in existing views, habits, conditions, or institutions*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/radical)

***modern*** (suggesting ‘inclined not to rely on tradition’): [*involving recent techniques, methods, or ideas*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/modern)

***ultramodern*** (suggesting ‘rather *determined* not to rely on tradition’!): [*beyond what is ordinary, proper, or moderate :  excessively :  extremely – **ultramodern***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ultra) (This is part of the definition of ‘ultra’.)

Answer (score 2):

You might consider, ***farsighted***

> : able to see things that are far away more clearly than things that are near
>
> : **able to predict what will or might happen in the future** : [**foresighted**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foresighted) (emphasis is mine)
>
> : made or done while thinking about what will happen in the future
>
> e.g. *plans made by farsighted city leaders*; *farsighted conservationists long ago realized that wilderness areas of breathtaking beauty needed to be protected from future development*
>
> [Nerriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/farsighted)

Answer (score 1):

***Forward-thinking*** countries -

Countries ***forming the vanguard of innovation***. (i.e. the foremost division of an army; the forefront or van (OED))

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest ***[pioneering](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/pioneering.html)*** which can mean

> Being advanced in development

or

> Preceding all others in time

It works well in this exact context.